# Unable to deploy a ruby application in Cloudfoundry

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cloud-foundry

I have the application ready
but when I am deploying I am facing an error
deployment facing error in heroku and cloud foundry

gems used are: event_calender
authlogic

error in : cloud foundry

```
wafuser@wafuser-VirtualBox:~/Documents/backups/backupnew/ecommerce$ vmc push
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: y
Application Name: shiva108
Detected a Rails Application, is this correct? [Yn]: y
Application Deployed URL [shiva108.cloudfoundry.com]: 
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [256M]: 
How many instances? [1]: 1
Create services to bind to 'shiva108'? [yN]: y
1: mongodb
2: mysql
3: postgresql
4: rabbitmq
5: redis
What kind of service?: 2
Specify the name of the service [mysql-ceaf3]: 
Create another? [yN]: n
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]: n
Creating Application: OK
Creating Service [mysql-ceaf3]: OK
Binding Service [mysql-ceaf3]: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (192K): OK   
Push Status: OK
Staging Application 'shiva108': OK                                              
Starting Application 'shiva108': .
Error: Application [shiva108] failed to start, logs information below.

====> /logs/migration.log <====
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for my problem

Comment: Can you show the `/logs/migration.log`

Comment: How many files do you have in db/migrations

Comment: You seem to be indicating that event_calendar authlogic has something to do with the problem. If you remove those references, does the cloudfoundry deployment work? Here are some ideas, 1) have you successfully deployed a simple app to cloudfoundry using the instructions at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/ruby/ruby-rails-sinatra.html )? 2) can you open a ticket at http://support.cloudfoundry.com/home and send us your app? We'll review, then post an answer here

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following command:

```
vmc logs <app-name>
```

This will give you the logs you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this commnd:

Heroku:

```
$ heroku logs
```

Cloud Foundry:

```
$ vmc files shiva108 logs/stderr.log
```

Comment: Hi sir thank you for your reply when i am trying the cloudfoundry $ vmc files shiva108 logs/stderr.log its is giving there is no such directory. Michael Durrant